# MongoDB: Mathematical operation without KEY

Tags: mongodb

The input data's in mongoDB collection is like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("dummyObjectID"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "src_ip" : "Source IP address",
            "dst_ip" : "Destination IP address",
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 1,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et1,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it1
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 2,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et2,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it2
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 3,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et3,
            "hop_latency" : 1122,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it3
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 4,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et4,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it4
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 5,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et5,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it5
        }
    ],
    "time" : dummyTime
}
```

My expectation is below output:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("dummyObjectID"),
    "data" : [
        {
            "src_ip" : "Source IP address",
            "dst_ip" : "Destination IP address",
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 1,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et1,
            "link_latency" : 0, # Here 0 because there is no switch before this switch
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it1
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 2,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et2,
            "link_latency" : it2 - et1,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it2
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 3,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et3,
            "link_latency" : it3 - et2,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it3
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 4,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et4,
            "link_latency" : it4 - et3,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it4
        },
        {
            "switchId" : 5,
            "egress_timeStamp" : et5,
            "link_latency" : it5 - et4,
            "hop_latency" : someValue,
            "ingress_timeStamp" : it5
        }
    ],
    "time" : dummyTime
}
```

I want to calculate link latency which is ['ingressTimestamp of current switch' - 'egressTimestamp of previous switch'] for each switchID. For first switchID, linkLatency must be '0'.
The problem I am facing is, switch data dont have keys; Therefore unable to perform this operation.

I am new to mongodb.
I am able to get required output using pyMongo and Python pandas dataframe but it takes lot of time.
I think there must be some good approach in mongoDB itself to get this required output.

Comment: Your input data is not valid JSON. Please update your question with the exact record.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Updated the JSON.

Answer (score 0):

No need to use pandas. You can build a new list entry from the current one; hopefully this is more efficient (n.b. it doesn't create the superfluous zero entry in the first record; amend as appropriate if this is really needed):

```
for record in db.mycollection.find({}):
    prev_et = None
    new_data = []
    for x in sorted(record['data'], key=lambda o: o.get('switch_id', '')):
        if prev_et is not None:
            x['link_latency'] = (x['ingress_timeStamp'] - prev_et).total_seconds()
        prev_et = x.get('egress_timeStamp', None)
        new_data.append(x)
    record['data'] = new_data
    db.mycollection.replace_one({'_id': record['_id']}, record, upsert=True)
```

Full example with data setup:

```
import pymongo
import datetime
from random import randint

db = pymongo.MongoClient()['mydatabase']

t = [datetime.datetime.utcnow()]

for i in range(1, 10):
    t.append(t[i - 1] + datetime.timedelta(milliseconds=randint(100, 1000)))

db.mycollection.insert_one({
    "data": [
        {
            "src_ip": "Source IP address",
            "dst_ip": "Destination IP address",
        },
        {
            "switchId": 1,
            "egress_timeStamp": t[0],
            "hop_latency": randint(100, 1000),
            "ingress_timeStamp": t[1]
        },
        {
            "switchId": 2,
            "egress_timeStamp": t[2],
            "hop_latency": randint(100, 1000),
            "ingress_timeStamp": t[3],
        },
        {
            "switchId": 3,
            "egress_timeStamp": t[4],
            "hop_latency": randint(100, 1000),
            "ingress_timeStamp": t[5],
        },
        {
            "switchId": 4,
            "egress_timeStamp": t[6],
            "hop_latency": randint(100, 1000),
            "ingress_timeStamp": t[7],
        },
        {
            "switchId": 5,
            "egress_timeStamp": t[8],
            "hop_latency": randint(100, 1000),
            "ingress_timeStamp": t[9],
        }
    ],
    "time": datetime.datetime.utcnow()
})

for record in db.mycollection.find({}):
    prev_et = None
    new_data = []
    for x in sorted(record['data'], key=lambda o: o.get('switch_id', '')):
        if prev_et is not None:
            x['link_latency'] = (x['ingress_timeStamp'] - prev_et).total_seconds()
        prev_et = x.get('egress_timeStamp', None)
        new_data.append(x)
    record['data'] = new_data
    db.mycollection.replace_one({'_id': record['_id']}, record, upsert=True)
```

Gives:

```
> db.mycollection.findOne()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5e06a4bf54e0e497307e43d8"),
        "data" : [
                {
                        "src_ip" : "Source IP address",
                        "dst_ip" : "Destination IP address"
                },
                {
                        "switchId" : 1,
                        "egress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:35.615Z"),
                        "hop_latency" : 949,
                        "ingress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:36.303Z")
                },
                {
                        "switchId" : 2,
                        "egress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:36.955Z"),
                        "hop_latency" : 953,
                        "ingress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:37.162Z"),
                        "link_latency" : 1.547
                },
                {
                        "switchId" : 3,
                        "egress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:37.475Z"),
                        "hop_latency" : 751,
                        "ingress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:38.032Z"),
                        "link_latency" : 1.077
                },
                {
                        "switchId" : 4,
                        "egress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:38.878Z"),
                        "hop_latency" : 961,
                        "ingress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:39.682Z"),
                        "link_latency" : 2.207
                },
                {
                        "switchId" : 5,
                        "egress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:40.096Z"),
                        "hop_latency" : 728,
                        "ingress_timeStamp" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:40.561Z"),
                        "link_latency" : 1.683
                }
        ],
        "time" : ISODate("2019-12-28T00:41:35.615Z")
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. The suggested logic worked for me. :)